# Moving a subview with CGRectMake causes crash

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I'm trying to move a subview on the click of a button but its crashing and giving me `-[MainGameDisplay openTimeChanger:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x10e443d0`

Here's what I'm doing:

```
@interface:
UIImageView *changerBackground;
@implementation

timerView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 278, 105, 27)];
[self.view addSubview:timerView];

changerBackground = [[UIImageView alloc] init];
[changerBackground setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"speedbackground.png"]];
changerBackground.frame = CGRectMake(-12 , 9, 105, 33);
[changerBackground setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
[timerView addSubview:changerBackground];

UIButton *timerBackground = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
[timerBackground setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Time Background.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[timerBackground setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Time Background.png"] forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
[timerBackground addTarget:self action:@selector(openTimeChanger:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
timerBackground.frame = CGRectMake(-2 , 15, 102, 27);
[timerView addSubview:timerBackground];



-(void)openTimeChanger {
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.2f
                     animations:^{
                         changerBackground.frame = CGRectMake(-12 , -16, 105, 33);
                     }
                     completion:Nil];
}
```

Would also like to note that changerBackground has 3 subviews.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change this,

```
[timerBackground addTarget:self action:@selector(openTimeChanger:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

to

```
[timerBackground addTarget:self action:@selector(openTimeChanger) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside]; //note that semicolon is not there in the method name
```

You method definition is `-(void)openTimeChanger` and not `-(void)openTimeChanger:(id)sender`. It was trying to find a method with this definition but the same was not available and hence the crash.

If you want to use `[timerBackground addTarget:self action:@selector(openTimeChanger:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];`, then change your method as `-(void)openTimeChanger:(id)sender`.

Comment: Oh god.. So simple.. Thank you.

Comment: @SinaYamani, Thanks. Kindly accept when it allows you to do so. :)

Comment: Yeah I was just waiting. Could I just quickly ask you how you could set the user interaction of a button off. I've tried userInteraction but it doesn't work. there are labels covering a button on mine that I need to click.

Comment: Are you asking about `button.enabled = NO;` which will disable a button?

Comment: No, when I disable it, it still blocks the button behind it. I want a way to have it become 'transparent' to clicks.

Comment: @SinaYamani, Sorry, I am getting confused. Can you please post this as a question with the complete code for that. We can have a look at that.

Comment: Also try hidden property. `button.hidden = YES;`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/20142/discussion-between-sina-yamani-and-acb)